# "Membership.Provider must be an instance of ExtendedMembershipProvider"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, membership-provider

I'm writing a MVC4 Website using Microsoft Visual Studio express 2012 for web.
Whenever I run "Update-Database" in the Package Manager Console, the following Exception occurs:

```
To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance
of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
```

This is my Seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(GNSystem.Models.DataContext context)
    {
        context.Forums.AddOrUpdate(
                        new Forum { ForumName = "Hello" },
                        new Forum { ForumName = "World" },
                        new Forum { ForumName = "!" }
                        );
        context.UserProfiles.Add(new UserAccount { UserName = "Gilad", EMail = "user@example.com" });
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("Gilad", "123456");
        WebSecurity.Login("Gilad", "123456");
        context.Threads.AddOrUpdate(
            new Thread { Subject = "FirstThread", Content = "Awesome Content", ForumID = 1, UserID = 1 },
            new Thread { Subject = "SecondThread", Content = "Awesome Content", ForumID = 1, UserID = 1 }
            );
    }
```

I searched for [solutions](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership) and added the following directive in the Web.config file:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
```

but the exception is thrown nonetheless.

What is the cause of this?
**Edit 1:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-GNSystem-20120913165926;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-GNSystem-20120913165926.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have a custom membership provider?

Comment: Do you have a membership section in your web.config?  Update your question with this.

Comment: No, I don't have it. I'll post the full Web.config

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before you can use `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("Gilad", "123456");` SimpleMembership must be initialized.  This is typically done on the AccountController with the `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` attribute, but since you're trying to call these methods within your Seed, you will need to initialize it another way.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected override void Seed(eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb context)
{
  context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(d => d.Name,
              new Department() { Name = "Engineering" },
              new Department() { Name = "Sales" },
              new Department() { Name = "Shipping" },
              new Department() { Name = "Human Resources" });

  if (!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
  {
    Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
  }

  if (Membership.GetUser("wayne") == null)
  {
    Membership.CreateUser("wayne", "P@ssword");
    Roles.AddUserToRole("wayne", "Admin");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the Membership provider you are using in this application inherits from MembershipProvider or ExtendedMembershipProvider. Make sure that it is inheriting from ExtendedMembershipProvider class.