# ASP.NET Web API compatible with SimpleMembershipProvider?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-membership, asp.net-web-api

Can the `SimpleMembershipProvider` be used with a `ApiController` or is it for classical web pages only? When trying to use it, I get the error "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of `ExtendedMembershipProvider`.

If it is compatible, how can I call the .`ValidateUser` method without creating a cookie like WebSecurity.Login does?

**UPDATE**

I got it running within a Web API scaffolding after the following changes:

1. `Web.config`: outcomment the default membership & role provider within the `system.web` tag, as inserted by the Web API scaffolding.
2. Change the template `InitializeSimpleMebershipAttribute` from a Mvc attribute to `System.Web.Http.Filters`. The attributes hook directly into the controller and Mvc doesn't work for an `ApiController`.

However, the `WebSecurity` class is intermingled with forms authentication and the `.Login` method attaches a cookie to the http-header. `WebMatrix.WebData` exposes `SimpleMembershipProvider`, but there is no `.ValidateUser` to use it in a neutral way regarding authentication.

Is `SimpleMembership` actually intended to be used with anything else than forms authentication? I cannot find a clear answer to that on the web.

Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, is it a better idea to use the AccountController from the MVC 3 template which uses the old MembershipProvider?

Comment: I am not sure about the validateuser part of your question but this question may help resolve your error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408349/membership-provider-must-be-an-instance-of-extendedmembershipprovider there is more info here about SimpleMembershipProvider http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the answer. [See the remarks section at the end of this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569035%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

After initializing a `SimpleMembershipProvider` with the `WebMatrix.WebData` methods, the `System.Web.Security.Membership` class is available, just as with the old `MembershipProvider`. Instead of using the `WebSecurity` class for validation, `Membership.ValidateUser` is available and no cookie attached to the http header.